# move elements into li elements according to its index (first element into first li and second element into second li and so on) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have these code

```html
<div class="images">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" class="image1">
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="image2">
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" class="image3">
</div>
```

and

```html
<ul id="attnd" class="class-attnd">
    <li class="liclass">some text1</li>
    <li class="liclass">some text2</li>
    <li class="liclass">some text3</li>
</ul>
```

in result I want all images from images div move  into li element accordingly its index means first image into first li and second into second li and so on

like this

```html
<ul id="attnd" class="class-attnd">
    <li class="liclass liclass-1">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" class="image1">
        <span class="spanclass-1">some text1</span>
    </li>
    <li class="liclass liclass-2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="image2">
        <span class="spanclass-2">some text2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="liclass liclass-3">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" class="image3">
        <span class="spanclass-3">some text3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this using jquery

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution: it iterates the `li` elements, and for each of them *moves* the next image into it, and wraps its text content into a `span` element:

```js
$("#attnd li").each(function (idx, li) {
    $(li).addClass("liclass-" + (idx+1)).append(
        $(".images img:first-child"),
        $("<span>").addClass("spanclass-" + (idx+1)).append($(li).contents())
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="img1" class="image1">
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="img2" class="image2">
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="img3" class="image3">
</div>

<ul id="attnd" class="class-attnd">
    <li class="liclass">some text1</li>
    <li class="liclass">some text2</li>
    <li class="liclass">some text3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your answer solved my problem and give me what I want but another problem created when another images div and ul added dynamically. Actually these code are generated from a repeater. When there is one entry all is well but when second entry added then images messes

Comment: Yes, when you have new images and lists added later, you'll have to make sure to only deal with the newly added content, and not add images to list items that already have images. If you cannot make it work, then post a new question where you include this dynamic loading (mimic it with a timer), and add your attempt.

Comment: I think you got my point, could you please give solution here. Thank you

Comment: Please make an attempt. If you cannot make it work, post a new question that includes your attempt and the problem you encountered. (Make sure the problem is reproducible as I indicated in my previous comment)